# Kivy: Accessing canvas properties inside of a widget from python

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, kivy

I need the size property of a canvas to change dynamically in a widget every half a second. Is there a way to access the size property from the python code? or can I bind a function to it in the kv code?

Here is my Kivy code:

```
    Widget:
        id: myWidget
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,1,1
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: (self.width, self.height / 2)
                pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas doesn't have a size property, I guess you mean the size of the RoundedRectangle?

In that case the simplest method is to bind it to a property and update the property:

```
size: self.rect_size
```

And in the python:

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
class YourWidget:
    rect_size = ListProperty([0, 0])
```

Note that the kv then needs to use the `YourWidget` class.

Update the `rect_size` and the RoundedRectangle size will automatically follow it.